# What is the topology defined on $[0, \omega_1)$ it and how do we define its basis?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, order-topology

The set $[0, \omega_1)$ is a countably compact topological space. How do we prove it to be a topological space. How does its basis elements look like?

Comment: There's quite a bit of [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) missing from your question which makes it rather difficult to understand, and to answer, without some further guesses as to what it might mean. Perhaps you could explain some of that context. For example, what is $\omega$? What are the elements of the set $[0,\omega)$? What additional structure does that set $[0,\omega)$ come equipped with?

Comment: By the above statement, i mean what actually is the set $[0,\omega)$. Exactly, how do its elements look like. What does its basis look like that generates a topology on it? What topology is it that makes it a topological space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is the [first uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal) which is a linearly ordered set, of size $\aleph_1$, and whose elements are all countable ordinals (so it starts with $0,1,2,\ldots,\omega, \omega+1, \omega+2, \ldots, \omega+\omega,\ldots$ and the order is a well-order (every non-empty subset has a minimum). The topology on this set is the standard order topology, which in this case is: $0$ and every successor ordinal $\alpha+1$ is an isolated point, and if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, a local base are all sets $(\beta,\alpha]$ where $\beta < \alpha$. All subsets of the form $(\alpha, \rightarrow)$ are also open.

A typical feature of $\omega_1$ is that every countable sequence $(\alpha_n)_n$ has a supremum in $[0,\omega_1)$. This is what causes it to be countably compact, but not compact. It's a commonly used counterexample, not only in topology but also in measure theory e.g.